# Join channels with form Slack

Tags: typescript, slack

What i want to do is to onboard a new user following a form. If a certain working area (IT, Marketing, etc) is selected then assign the channels according that area.

Is it possible?.

Thanks!

I did some functions and the main goal is to have a form in where i can choose some area and then join specifics channels.

Comment: What have you tried? Please show us some code.

Comment: Well, im using the no-code version of Slack to make Apps. Maybe i should make some hibrid no-code with code version so i can achive what i want.
Can you help me with the code part?.

What i was thinking is to have a database with the company areas (marketing, IT, finance, etc) and then link the channels that match every sector. Maybe there is another way to do it....